# Perl i can't decode from utf-8 to greek language

Tags: json, perl, utf-8

I am taking a JSON document from the messenger platform and I want to compare the `$message_text` with Greek words. After I am decode it from UTF-8, the problem is that the decode isn't happening and `$message_text` has the same value (`"\xce\x93\xce\xb5\xce\xb9\xce\xb1"`) before and after the decode.This is my code now.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use CGI;
use HTTP::Daemon;
use HTTP::Status;
use Encode qw(decode encode);
use DBI;
use utf8;
use Encode;


my $message_payload;
my $message_sender_id;


sub decode_json_reply{
  #Decoding the message we recieved from the messenger
  my $json_text = shift;

  warn "Callback_Messages_Testa1:".$json_text;


  my $message_res = JSON::decode_json($json_text);

  my $message_text = $message_res->{entry}[0]->{messaging}[0]->{message}->{text};
  $message_sender_id = $message_res->{entry}[0]->{messaging}[0]->{sender}->{id};
  my $message_recipient_id = $message_res->{entry}[0]->{messaging}[0]->{recipient}->{id};
  $message_payload = $message_res->{entry}[0]->{messaging}[0]->{postback}->{payload};
  my $message_watermark = $message_res->{entry}[0]->{messaging}[0]->{delivery}->{watermark};


  $message_text = Encode::decode_utf8($message_text);


  if("Γεια" eq $message_text){
    warn "DONE-GREEK";
  }



}
```

This the json i am getting back from messenger platform

`{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"434218046923911","time":149‌​4249616799,"messagin‌​g":[{"sender":{"id":‌​"1184989524957707"},‌​"recipient":{"id":"4‌​34218046923911"},"ti‌​mestamp":14942496163‌​87,"message":{"mid":‌​"mid.$cAAGK6wcXaFtiG‌​Xz8A1b6DJt38to5","se‌​q":667346,"text":"\\‌​u0393\\u03b5\\u03b9\‌​\u03b1"}}]}]}`

```
<%

my $query = $Request->BinaryRead();


decode_json_reply($query);


%>
```

Comment: i know i have used eq too but the same problem.Also this is the json i take from the messenger platfrom and i am taking the text field for comparison with the "Γεια": {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"434218046923911","time":1494249616799,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"1184989524957707"},"recipient":{"id":"434218046923911"},"timestamp":1494249616387,"message":{"mid":"mid.$cAAGK6wcXaFtiGXz8A1b6DJt38to5","seq":667346,"text":"\\u0393\\u03b5\\u03b9\\u03b1"}}]}]}

Comment: it seems not but when i warn the $message_text it gives me utf-8 symbols \xce\x93\xce\xb5\xce\xb9\xce\xb1

Comment: it's copy paste from the error log,the json is fine i have tested with english characters

Comment: what did you mean by input??i give you the json.

Comment: i am reading data from the messenger platform callback that occurs when a text message is sent to my page. This is the link for the messenger platform documentation about the json text https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message. Also i edit the post with the webhook.asp that reads the data

Comment: The data you show isn't valid JSON and the `JSON` module will not parse it. Please dump `$json_text` from Perl using `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; print Dumper $json_text;` and show us the output from that.

Comment: This is the output {\\"object\\":\\"page\\",\\"entry\\":[{\\"id\\":\\"434218046923911\\",\\"time\\":1494253318253,\\"messaging\\":[{\\"sender\\":{\\"id\\":\\"1184989524957707\\"},\\"recipient\\":{\\"id\\":\\"434218046923911\\"},\\"timestamp\\":1494253317826,\\"message\\":{\\"mid\\":\\"mid.\\$cAAGK6wcXaFtiGbV2wlb6GrnuFJAh\\",\\"seq\\":667376,\\"text\\":\\"\\\\u0393\\\\u03b5\\\\u03b9\\\\u03b1\\"}}]}]}

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? Surely there are some quotes around it, and all those backslashes shouldn't be doubled up. Also, the `$` isn't escaped when it should be. How are you viewing the result of `print`?

Comment: i can't print it in a browser because this page is running as a callback when i am sending a text to the facebook page. So i am warning it out in the error_log

Comment: You can't do that. The logging is clearly adding a lot of junk that isn't in the original string. Can you open a file and write it to that instead, then dump the result|?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You need `use utf8` at the top of your file to say that its contents are UTF=8-encoded
- You need to compare the string with `eq`, not `=`, and you must add `use warnings 'all'` to warn you of errors like that
- To print UTF-8 data you should work with *characters* and set your output stream to use UTF-8 with `use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf8) /`
- Perl's internal string encoding is based on UTF-8, so you won't see any difference between the output of UTF-encoded bytes and unencoded Perl characters

---

#### Update

Here's a version of your code that provides the correct result. I have used what I think is the original data that the logging process has corrupted. If you can spot a difference between this and your own code then you have found the problem

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use JSON 'decode_json';

my $json_text = q<{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"434218046923911","time":1494253318253,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"1184989524957707"},"recipient":{"id":"434218046923911"},"timestamp":1494253317826,"message":{"mid":"mid.$cAAGK6wcXaFtiGbV2wlb6GrnuFJAh","seq":667376,"text":"\u0393\u03b5\u03b9\u03b1"}}]}]}>;

my $message_res = decode_json( $json_text );

my $message_text;

for ( $message_res->{entry}[0]{messaging}[0] ) {

    $message_text = $_->{message}{text};
}

say "DONE-GREEK3" if $message_text eq "Γεια";
```

#### output

```
DONE-GREEK3
```

Comment: I am using use utf8 and eq.The problem isn't the print but the comparison between a greek word like "Γεια" and the text i take from the json.